# Why use key lookup instead of rid lookup since rid lookup is faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, lookup

Does anyone know why use a key lookup instead of RID lookup to search for the data since RID lookup is definitely faster than a key lookup when you have a non-clustered index on a clustered index? Like you can already get the RID/address why even bother read from the root node traversing several levels to get what you want?

Comment: You need to provide some details about the scenario, table definition, indexes, query, execution plan.

Comment: What are you referring to?  Databases usually have row ids in secondary indexes for this purpose.

Comment: @DaleK - Seems to be a general question about SQL Server's design decision to include the (logical) clustered index key as the row locator in non clustered indexes when the table has a CI, as opposed to  just using the physical RID as it does for a heap.

Answer (score 0):

Data is stored in 8K pages within extents.  If the table has no clustered index it is called a heap and the last bytes are a vector of 2-byte addresses which point to the data row addresses on that page.  These are called the RIDs or Row IDs.

When a heap gets a clustered index (there can only ever be one), the vector of RID addresses gets converted into a vector of key addresses.  This allows SQL Server to use the same page structure for both heaps and clustered (indexed) tables.

So the answer to your question is that a clustered table has lost its RIDs and the only strategy is to use key lookup.  Mind you, even having RIDs on a heap involves scanning the IAM pages for the data page address, so any 'savings' are questionable.

Comment: "Extents are a collection of eight physically contiguous pages and are used to efficiently manage the pages. All pages are organized into extents." -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: A rid is a File, Page, Slot. Clustered index rows exist on pages in files and have a slot on the page so there is no reason a physical RID can't be used for those. Likely it wouldn't be a good idea though as the slot array is in key order so inserting a row into a page could cause tens or hundreds of slot indexes to change and need to be updated in non clustered indexes

Answer (score 0):

A RID is a logical address containing three constituents.

- File
- Page
- Slot

This concept does exist for heaps and clustered indexes. You can see it with

```
SELECT sys.fn_physlocformatter(%%physloc%%), *
FROM your_table
```

I imagine the reason that a physical RID is not used for clustered indexes is the maintenance costs would be too high. The [slot array](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/) is in key order so inserting a new row on a page where all the existing rows have later key order would mean that potentially hundreds of rows get their slot number incremented and need to be updated in all non clustered indexes.

For heaps there is no need to rearrange the slot array on insert as it does not have to maintain any particular order. For heaps on update if a row expands and can no longer fit in its original position a forwarding pointer is left thus saving the need to update the RID in nonclustered indexes for even that single row.

Some of this overhead could be avoided by having a physical address with just the `File:Page` components and looking up the key value on the page itself (in the same way as happens once the leaf page is located through a regular index seek) but still there could be operations where many rows get their PID invalidated and would need to have this effect propagated out to the nonclustered indexes (such as page splits or index rebuilds).

Decoupling the logical pointer from the physical location of the row does also allow indexes to be migrated to different file groups with less overhead.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, thank you so much!